# ext3 vs ext4 bonnie++ rand/seq create speed

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3

I am testing the difference between ext3 and ext4 for our application. When I run both filesystems through a bonnie++ test, the results for file creation on ext4 aren't very good. While ext3 can create 380 files/sec, ext4 manages a mere 38 files/sec.

here is the command I run:

```
bonnie++ -u 0 -r 3460 -s 10240 -n 256 -b -d /bench/
```

Both tests run on the same, empty, physical disk. Both filesystems are formatted and mounted without additional options.

Can someone give me some insight in to why these values differ so much ? Or if I'm making making some (obvious) mistake.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem. On our 2.8 kernel, Ext3 write barriers where disabled by default, while they where enabled for Ext4. Disabling the option on Ext4 drastically increased our create/delete speeds for bonnie++. Currently running crash tests to check the reliability but so far so good.